# How to integrate the following expression?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, error-function

I want to know what is the best way to integrate the following expression and get the simplest answer
$$
\int_{u_-}^{u^+}
   \frac{1}{r_1r_2}
   \exp\left(\left[r_1^2+r_2^2-2u\right]^{1/2}+4su\right)du \tag{1}
$$ 
I tried it by Mathematica and got
$$
\frac{1}{16 s^{3/2}}
\left(
 4e^{\sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2-2u}+4su}\sqrt{s}
+ e^{\frac{1}{8s}+2\left[r_1^2+r_2^2\right]s}
  \sqrt{2\pi}\
  \mathrm{Erf}\left[\frac{1-4s\sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2-2u}}{2\sqrt{2s}}\right]
\right) \tag{2}
$$
which must be calculated for $u_-$ and $u_+$. Is there any way to get a simpler answer, preferably without Error function?

Comment: No, if $s \ne 0$ then you cannot avoid erf in your answer.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks, yes $s$ is not zero.